# When does MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendSubject() return false?

Tags: ios, swift, messageui

I am using the iOS MessageUI framework to present a Message View Controller using MFMessageComposeViewController. I do not understand the return value from canSendSubject(). Apple docs say:

> **canSendSubject()**
>
> Indicates whether or not messages can include subject lines, according
> to the user’s configuration in Settings.

In my testing, canSendSubject() always returns true despite various combinations of switches in *Settings: Messages*. I expected the *Show Subject Field* switch setting would influence the return value, but it doesn't.

**Does anyone know under what condition canSendSubject() will return false?**

```
func displayMessagingUI() {
    
    let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.recipients = [String(8005551212)]
    composeVC.body = "This is a test message."
    
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendSubject() {
        composeVC.subject = "Subject"
    }
    
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

*Testing on iOS 11.1, iPhone X*

Comment: I am not asking how a user can turn on and off subject lines in Settings. I am asking a developer API question, so, no, explain how to change user settings is not useful. The point that may be missed is I *am* turning on and off the user setting for subject lines in message and the return value from the API call MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendSubject() is *not* changing (as one would expect it to). So I am simply asking under what circumstances does this API call return false?

Comment: @markquezada I never discovered under what conditions .canSendSubject() returns false. The only thought I had was that possibly it may be related to the receiver's carrier or current cellular network or something.

Comment: I filed a radar explaining this and linking to this SO page. We'll see if anything comes of it.

Answer (score -2):

canSendSubject()

> Indicates whether or not messages can include subject lines, according
>   to the user’s configuration in Settings.

and these settings you can enable or disable.If setting is disable it will return false.

for more info you can visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller).

Comment: you just re posted part of my question, not sure how that is helpful.

Comment: @Swany have you checked my shared link?

Comment: @sagar share also some useful thing, but that is also unuseful for you.I think you want different thing and your question is wrong.

Comment: This answer isn't helpful. OP's not trying to enable or disable a feature in the OS.